# Removing Linking Files from Excel

Tags: excel

When opening an excel file, in the bottom right corner of Excel it will **"download"** the file and then it goes through a process of **"Linking: Report Y.xls"** (edited for security reasons). This report adds considerable time to the model opening, and I cannot seem to find it anywhere in the file. I have removed named ranges, searched for .xls, checked pivots/tables, broken links, etc. Any thoughts for finding hidden connections?

Comment: I suppose I should be more clear: I have no idea where this item is to break it. There is nothing in edit links, nothing appears to be named, in formulas, etc. So I need a way to find it first.

Answer (score 0):

Try the FindLink add-in by Bill Manville to uncover links in worksheet artefacts.

Check data connections.

Check VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check (if any) macros, drop-down menus, charts and other objects? These cannot be found by searching for ".xls"